# python function, float object as parameter

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, parameters

When I try to run my code I get this error message: "only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars".
How can I adjust my code to fit the float parameters I want?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sqrt, pi, tan
import numpy as np
g = 9.81
s = 7.9*10**(-2)
p = 1000
h = 50

x_array = np.linspace(0.001, 0.1)
y_array = sqrt(((g*x_array)/(2*pi))*(1+((4*s*pi**2)/(p*g*x_array**2)))*tan(h)*((2*pi*h)/(x_array)))

plt.plot(x_array, y_array, '.r-', markersize=4)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Don't use `math` but `numpy` instead.

Comment: will this work if I don't import from math?

Comment: Leave out `math` completely. Don't import anything from math, always import from numpy